# I want to convert xlsx file to CSV file with ^ Caret Delimited Symbol

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a huge Excel file with 50k + rows and 400+ columns.  I am trying to write java code to export to a CSV file, but it is not working properly (giving error heap and stack).

Then I split that excel file into 5k rows by using macros, then successfully generating the CSV file but some data is not coming in csv file.  I have verified using the Excel application in **Data > Get External Data from Text** to csv.  We have to pass all those information that I have applied from filter then it is showing Blanks option. Some rows not getting data in CSV file.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class ExcelToCSV {

    static List<StringBuilder> dataList = new ArrayList();

static void convertXlsxToCSVF(File inputFile) 
{
        // For storing data into CSV files

try 
{
        // Get the workbook instance for XLSX file
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);



        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
        StringBuilder cellValue = new StringBuilder();
        row = rowIterator.next();

        // For each row, iterate through each columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
                cell = cellIterator.next();
                String test = null;
                switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                {

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    test = String.valueOf(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    test = test.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                        cellValue.append(test + "^");
                        break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    test = String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    test = test.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                        cellValue.append( test+ "^");
                        break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    test = cell.getStringCellValue().toString().trim();
                    test = test.replaceAll("\n", " ");
                        cellValue.append( test + "^");
                        break;

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        cellValue.append("" + "^");
                        break;

                default:
                        cellValue.append(cell + "^");

                }
        }
        if(cellValue.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Here is my all columns name with ceperated ^")){
        continue;   
        }else{
        dataList.add(cellValue);
        }
        cellValue = null;
        }
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
        System.err.println("Exception :" + e.getMessage());
}
finally{
    System.gc();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/TSR/Desktop/test/");
        //File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/TSR/Desktop/ETL/TSR.xlsx");

        File[] flist = inputFile.listFiles();
        System.out.println("xlsx file generating --->");
        StringBuilder b= new StringBuilder("Here is my all columns name with ceperated ^");
        dataList.add(b);
        for(int i=0;i<flist.length;i++){
            File dataFile = new File(flist[i].getAbsolutePath());
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    convertXlsxToCSVF(dataFile);
            }
        });
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("generated file :: "+ i);
        }
        try{
        File outputFile = new File("C:/Users/TSR/Desktop/test/TSR.csv");
        BufferedWriter bw;
        if(outputFile.exists()){
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile,true));
        }else{
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
        }
        for(int i=0;i<dataList.size();i++){
            bw.write(dataList.get(i).toString());
            bw.write("\n");
        }
        bw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println("csv file generated successfully");
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show sample inputs/outputs. Also, CSV is "comma separated values." Is that what you want, or do you want caret separated?

Comment: I want the Caret separated file.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the POI usermodel, which reads the entire worksheet into memory. Don't. Use the POI eventmodel instead.

Also, you're building the result up in memory. Don't. Write the rows as they are processed.

Streaming both input (POI eventmodel) and output (using a `Writer`), you memory footprint will drop to almost nothing, and you will not run out of memory, no matter how large the Excel document is.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to replace `String test` by `StringBuilder test and rework your code with that. Because all the operation like`test = test.replaceAll("\n", " ");` are creating another string in the memory. Hence the heap problem.